# Fortran error with the FORMAT statement

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I'm trying to compile some Fortran code but I keep getting errors with the FORMAT statement. It says I'm missing brackets and characters but it looks fine to me. I am compiling it with silverfrost. The code is shown below:

```
!  PROGRAM  TO  SOLVE DEEP-BED DRYING  MODEL
!
!  BASIC  STATEMENTS
!
CHARACTER*20  FiIe1, File2
COMMON  AMo
COMMON  /DENS/  Pmo,  Pme
COMMON  /THICK/ dxo,  Dxe

DIMENSION  AM1(50),  AM2(50),  T(50),  Gs(51),  Vs(51), Ts(51), Dx(50), X(50)
!
!To  define a  number  of  statement  functions

AMe(Ts)=0.62*EXP(-1.116*(Ts-100)**0.3339)
A(Ts, Vs)=(1.2925-0.00058*Ts) * (0.9991-0.0963*Vs)
AK(Ts, Vs)=(0.00273*Ts-0.2609)*(2.0984*Vs+0.2174)
AN(Ts)=0.00222*Ts+0.9599
Ps(Ts)=0.7401-0.001505*Ts
!
!INPUT SECTION OF THE PROGR.A,M
!

PRINT*, 'Input the mass of the sample (g) :'
READ*, Wo
PRINT*, 'Input the initial moisture content (db):'
READ*, AMo
PRINT*, 'lnput the depth of the sample bed (mm):'
READ*, Xo
PRINT*, 'Input the number of layers in the bed:'
READ*, Nx
PRINT*, 'Input the steam temperature at inlet (oC):'
READ*, Tso
PRINT*, 'input the steam flow rate at inlet (kg/(m2.s)):'
READ*, Gso
PRINT*, 'lnput the expected drying time (min):'
READ*, Timeo
PRINT*, 'lnput the time interval- (min) :'
READ*, Dt

!
! TO DEFINE AND OPEN DATA FILES
!
PRINT*, 'Name for the file recording the simulation +process:'
READ*, File1
OPEN (1, FILE=File1)
PRINT*, 'Name for the file recording major data:'
READ*, File2
OPEN (2, FILE=File2)
!
! TO WRITE INPUTTED PARAMETERS IN THE DATA FILES
!
WRITE (1, *) 'Mass of sample:', Wo, ' g'
WRITE (1, *) 'Initial moisture content:', AMo, ' kg/kg'
WRITE (1, *) 'Depth of sample bed:', Xo, 'mm'
WRITE (1, *) 'Number of layers in sample bed:', Nx
WRITE (1, *) 'Steam temperature at inlet', Tso, 'deg C'
WRITE (1, *) 'Steam flow rate at inlet', Gso, 'kg/m2s'
WRITE (1, *) 'Expected drying time', Timeo, ' min'
WRITE (1, *) 'Time interval:', Dt, ' min'
!
WRITE (2, *) 'Mass of sample', Wo, 'g'
WRITE (2, *) 'Initial moisture content', AMo, 'kg/kg'
WRITE (2, *) 'Depth of sample bed', Xo, 'mm'
WRITE (2, *) 'Number of layers in sample bed', Nx
WRITE (2, *) 'Steam temperature at inlet', Tso, ' deg C'
WRITE (2, *) 'Steam flow rate at inlet', Gso, ' kg/m2*s'
WRITE (2, *) 'Expected drying time', Timeo, ' min'
WRITE (2, *) 'Time interval:', Dt, ' min'
!
!BASIC CALCULATION BASED ON THE INPUT DATA
!
Dxo=Xo/1000/Nx
Dxe=0.867*Dxo
D1=0.066
Pmo=4*(Wo/l000)/(3.14159*D1**2*(Xo/1000)*(1+AMo))
Pme=Pmo/0.867
AMeo=AMe(Tso)
NT=NINT(Timeo/Dt)
Pso=Ps(Tso)
Vso=Gso/Pso
!
!TO SET VALUES FOR SOME PHYSTCAL AND THERMODYNAMTC PROPERTIES
!
Cs=2000
Cw1=4193
Cw=4313
C=1245
!
!TO CALCULATE THE INTTIAL MOISTURE CONTENT CONSIDERING STEAM CONDENSATION
!
AMo1=AMo+(C+Cw1*AMo)/(2257000+Cs*(Tso-100))*(100-10)
!
!TO SET JUDGE CRITERION FOR TERMINATING THE DRYING OF A LAYER
!(A small difference between moisture content and equilibrium moisture content)
DM=0.0001
!
!MAJOR DERIVATION FOR DRYING SIMULATION
!
J=0
Time=0
m=1
!
WRITE(2, 100)
100 FORMAT(4H  J, 9H  T(min), 8H  M(db),7H  Gs , 10H  Ts(C) ,9H Front1, 5H  L1, 9H  Front2, 5h L2, 9H  Depth)
!
200 m5=m-1
    IF (J .GT. Nt) GO to 800
!
    PRINT*, ' ' 
    PRINT*, ' ' 
    PRINT*, 'Time inverval:', J, '   Drying time:', Time, ' min'
    WRITE(1, x) ' ' 
    WRITE(1, *) 'Time interval:', J, '   Drying time:', Time, ' min'
    WRITE(*, 300)
    WRITE(1, 300)
300 FORMAT(1x, 3H, I, 7H, X(i), 8H  M(i), 10H   T(i), 10H   Gs(i), 8H   Ts(i))
!
    AveM=0
!
!   For dried region
!
    IF(m .GT. 1) THEN
        DO 500 i=1, m-1
            Dx(i)=Dxe
            X(i)=(i-0.5)*Dxe
            AM1(i)=AM2(i)
            T(i)=Tso
            Gs(i)=Gso
            Vs(i)=Vso
            Ts(i)=Tso
            AveM=AveM+AM1(i)
            WRITE(*, 400) i, X(i), AM1(i), T(i), Gs(i), Ts(i)
            WRITE(1, 400) i, X(i), AM1(i), T(i), Gs(i), Ts(i)
400         FORMAT(1X, I3, 2X, F6.4, 2X, F6.4, 2X, F8.3, 2X, F7.3, 2X, F7.3)
500     CONTINUE
    ENDIF
!   Calculation of the drying front position
    IF (m .EQ. l) THEN
            X1=-1
            No1=-1
        ELSE
            Xl=X(m-1)+Dx(m-1)/2
            No1=m-1
    ENDIF
!
    IF (m .GT. Nx) GO TO 900
!
    Ts(m)=Tso
    Vs(m)=Vso
    L=0
    DO 600 i=m, Nx
        IF(L .NE.0) GO TO 510
!
!   For drying region
!
    If (J .EQ. O) THEN
        Am1(i)=AMo1
       Else
         AM1(i)=AM2(i)
       ENDIF
      Dx(i)=Dxx(AM1(i))
      IF (i .EQ. 1) THEN
        X(i)=Dx(i)/2
        ELSE
          X(i)=X(i-1)+Dx(i-1)/2+Dx(i)/2
        ENDIF
!
!   To define transition variables
!
    AMe5=AMe(Ts(i))
    A5=A(Ts(i),Vs(i))
    AK5=AK(Ts(i),Vs(i))
    AN5=AN(Ts(i))
    Ps5=Ps(Ts(i))
    P5=P(AMl(i))
    Dt5=Dt* 60
    !
    !   Derivation
    !
    AMmax=A5*(AMo-AMe5)/EXP((AN5-1)/AN5)+AMe5
        IF (AM1(i) .GE. AMmax) THEN
            AM2(i)=AM1(i)-Dt5*AK5*AN5*(AMmax-AMe5)*(ALOG(A5*(AMo-AMe5)/(AMmax-AMe5))/AK5)**((AN5-1)/AN5)/60
    ELSE
            AM2(i)=AM1(i)-Dt5*AK5*AN5*(AM1(i)-AMe5)*(ALOG(A5*(AMo-AMe5)/(AM1(i)-AMe5))/AK5)**((AN5-1)/AN5)/60
    ENDIF
DR=(AM2(i)-AM1(i))/Dt5
!
        IF (AM1(i) .GE. AMo) THEN
            T(i)=100
            DerT=0
            ELSE
                T(i)=Tso-(Tso-100)*(AM1(i)-AMeo)/(AMo-AMeo)
                DerT=-(Tso-l00)/(AMo-AMeo)*DR
            ENDIF
!
Gs(i)=Vs(i)*Ps5
Gs(i+l)=Gs(i)-Dx(i)*P5*DR
Vs(i+1)=Gs(i+1)/Ps5
Hv5=Hv(AMl(i), T(i))
Ts(i+1)=Ts(i)+Dx(i)*P5*(Hv5+Cs*(Ts(i)-T(i)))/(Gs(i)*Cs)*DR-Dx(i)*P5*(C+Cw*AMl(i))/(Gs(i)*Cs)*DerT
!
!   To find the first layer in wet region
!
    IF (Ts(i+l) .LE. l00) THEN
        Ts(i+1)=100
        L=i
    ENDIF
!
!   To check if the layer has been dried to equilibrium
!
        IF ((AM2(i)-AMeo) .LE. DM) THEN
            m5=i
            AM2(i)=AMeo
            ENDIF
        GO TO 520
!
!   For wet region
!
510     AM1(i)=AMo1
        AM2(i)=AMo1
        T(i)=100
        Gs(i+l)=Gs(i)
        Vs(i+1)=Vs(i)
        Ts(i+1)=100
!
        Dx(i)=Dxx(AM1(i)) 
        IF (i .EQ. 1) THEN
            X(i)=Dx(i)/2
            ELSE
                X(i)=X(i-1)+Dx(i-1)/2+Dx(i)/2
            ENDIF
!
520     AveM=AveM+AM1(i)
        WRITE(*, 400) i, X(i), AM1(i), T(i), Gs(i), Ts(i)
        WRITE(1, 400) i, X(i), AM1(i), T(i), Gs(i), Ts(i)
600 CONTINUE
!
!   Calculation of wet front position
        IF (L .EQ. O) THEN
            X2=-1
            No2=-1
           ELSE
             X2=X(L)+Dx(L)/2
             No2=L+1
             ENDIF
!
      AveM=AveM/Nx
      Depth=X(Nx)+Dx(Nx)/2
!
    WRITE(*, 100)
    WRITE(*, 700) J, Time, AveM, Gs(Nx*1), Ts(Nx*1), XI, No1, X2, No2, Depth
    WRITE (2, 700) J, Time, AveM, Gs(Nx+1), Ts(Nx*1), X1, No1, X2, No2, Depth
700 FORMAT(I4, 2X, F7.3, 2X, F6.4, 2X, F6.4, 2X, F7.3, 2X, F7.4, 2x, I3, 2X, F7.4, 2X, I3, 2x, F7.4)
!
    J=J+1
    Time=Time+Dt
    m=m5+1
    GO TO 200
!
800 PRINT*, ' '
    PRINT*, 'The drying time was up to the specified time.'
    PRINT*, 'The drying simulation was stopped.'
    PRINT*, 'The sample was not dried to equilibrium'
    WRITE(1,*)  ' '
    WRITE(1,*) 'The drying time was up to the specified time.'
    WRITE(1,*) 'The drying simulation was stopped'
    WRITE(1,*) 'The sample was not dried to equilibrium'
    WRITE(1,*) ' '
    WRITE(2,*) 'The drying time was up to the specified time'
    WRITE(2,*) 'The drying simulation was stopped'
    WRITE(2,*) 'The drying simulation was stopped'
    WRITE(2,*) 'The sample was not dried to equilirbium'
    GO TO 910
!
900 No2=-1
    X2=-1
    AveM=AveM/Nx
    WRITE(*, 100)
    WRITE(*, 700) J, Time, AveM, Gs(Nx+1), Ts(Nx+1), X1, No1, X2, No2, Depth
    WRITE(2, 700) J, Time, AveM, Gs(Nx+1), Ts(Nx+1), X1, No1, X2, No2, Depth
!
    PRINT*, ' '
    PRINT*, 'The sample was dried to equilibrium'
    PRINT*, 'The drying simulation was stopped.'
    WRITE(1,*)  ' '
    WRITE(1,*) 'The sample was dried to equilibrium'
    WRITE(1,*) 'The drying simulation was stopped'
    WRITE(2,*) ' '
    WRITE(2,*) 'The sample was not dried to equilirbium'
    WRITE(2,*) 'The drying simulation was stopped'
!
910 CLOSE(1)
    CLOSE(2)

END
!
!**********************************************************************************
!
!   EXTERNAL FUNCTION FOR LATENT HEAT OF EVAPORATION
!
        FUNCTION Hv(AM, T)
        Hfg=2257000-2916.7*(T-100)
        IF (AM .GE. 0.2) THEN
                Hv=Hfg
            ELSE
                Hv=Hfg*(1+EXP(-19.9*AM))
        ENDIF

        RETURN
        END
!
!   EXTERNAL FUNCTION FOR BULK DENSITY
!
        FUNCTION P(AM)
        COMMON AMo/DENS/ Pmo, Pme
        IF (AM .GE. AMo) THEN
            P=Pmo
            ELSE IF (AM .LT. 0.11) THEN
                P=Pme
            ELSE
                P=Pmo-(Pmo-Pme)*(AMo-AM)/(AMo-0.11)
            ENDIF
        RETURN
        END
!
!   EXTERNAL FUNCTION FOR LAYER THICKNESS
!
        FUNCTION Dxx(AM)
        COMMON AMo/THICK/ Dxo, Dxe
        IF (AM .GE. AMO) THEN
            Dxx=Dxo
            ELSE IF (AM .LT. 0.11) THEN
                Dxx=Dxe
            ELSE
                Dxx=Dxo-(Dxo-Dxe)*(AMo-AM)/(AMo-0.11)
            ENDIF
        RETURN
        END
!
!****************************************************************************************
```

And the errors are shown below:

```
Compiling and linking file: SHSDRYING.F95
C:\Users\steva\Desktop\SHSDRYING.F95(104) : error 58 - Unpaired right bracket(s)
C:\Users\steva\Desktop\SHSDRYING.F95(45) : error 259 - Scalar, default-kind, CHARACTER expression expected for the FILE keyword
C:\Users\steva\Desktop\SHSDRYING.F95(45) : warning 868 - Opening unit 1 may affect the operation of input from the default unit '*' - are you sure you want to do this?
C:\Users\steva\Desktop\SHSDRYING.F95(48) : warning 868 - Opening unit 2 may affect the operation of output to the default unit '*' - are you sure you want to do this?
C:\Users\steva\Desktop\SHSDRYING.F95(116) : warning 792 - Comma missing in format
C:\Users\steva\Desktop\SHSDRYING.F95(116) : warning 792 - Comma missing in format
C:\Users\steva\Desktop\SHSDRYING.F95(116) : error 270 - Missing width count for 'G' descriptor
C:\Users\steva\Desktop\SHSDRYING.F95(116) : warning 792 - Comma missing in format
C:\Users\steva\Desktop\SHSDRYING.F95(116) : error 274 - Unknown edit descriptor '(', or missing comma
C:\Users\steva\Desktop\SHSDRYING.F95(292) : warning 868 - Closing unit 1 may affect the operation of input from the default unit '*' - are you sure you want to do this?
C:\Users\steva\Desktop\SHSDRYING.F95(293) : warning 868 - Closing unit 2 may affect the operation of output to the default unit '*' - are you sure you want to do this?
C:\Users\steva\Desktop\SHSDRYING.F95(103) : error 90 - FORMAT label 100 does not exist
Compilation failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Unit 5,6 and 1,2 (and others) are reserved... If you make UNIT=1 become UNIT=21 and UNIT=2 become UNIT=22 it will work.

Better is probably to use NEWUNIT

```
!  PROGRAM  TO  SOLVE DEEP-BED DRYING  MODEL
!
!  BASIC  STATEMENTS
!
PROGRAM DEEP_BED_DRYING               !New
IMPLICIT NONE                         !New
CHARACTER*20  FiIe1, File2
COMMON  AMo
COMMON  /DENS/  Pmo,  Pme
COMMON  /THICK/ dxo,  Dxe
...
OPEN (NEWUNIT=MyUnit1, FILE=File1)    !New
WRITE(*,*)' Unit1=',MyUnit1           !New
...
OPEN (NEWUNIT=MyUnit2, FILE=File2)    !New
WRITE(*,*)' Unit2=',MyUnit2           !New
enter code here
!WRITE(1,*) ...
WRITE(MyUnit1,*) ...
```

IMPLICIT NONE is not a bad habit to get into using.
I would line up things for ease of reading...

```
WRITE (1, *) 'Mass of sample:'                 , Wo    , ' g'
WRITE (1, *) 'Initial moisture content:'       , AMo   , ' kg/kg'
WRITE (1, *) 'Depth of sample bed:'            , Xo    , 'mm'
WRITE (1, *) 'Number of layers in sample bed:' , Nx 
WRITE (1, *) 'Steam temperature at inlet'      , Tso   , 'deg C'
WRITE (1, *) 'Steam flow rate at inlet'        , Gso   , 'kg/m2s'
WRITE (1, *) 'Expected drying time'            , Timeo , ' min'
WRITE (1, *) 'Time interval:'                  , Dt    , ' min'
```

You either need to compile with -132 or use line continuation...

.F77 or -fixed compiler switch (Anything n Column #6):

```
      WRITE(2, 100)
100   FORMAT(4H  J, 9H  T(min), 8H  M(db),7H  Gs , 10H  Ts(C) ,
!234567
     &       9H Front1, 5H  L1, 9H  Front2, 5h L2, 9H  Depth)
```

.F90 or -free compiler switch (& at the end):

```
WRITE(2, 100)                                                 !Here
100 FORMAT(4H  J, 9H  T(min), 8H  M(db),7H  Gs , 10H  Ts(C) ,  &
!234567
           9H Front1, 5H  L1, 9H  Front2, 5h L2, 9H  Depth)
```

Comment: Opening preconnected unit numbers cause problems at runtime, not at compile time.

Comment: How do we explain the compiler messages complaining about unit 1 & 2? (The many compilers can all be different)

Comment: Read the warning message - it is talking about potential problems with runtime behaviour.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by using NEWUNIT, is it a placeholder?

Comment: I think it was introduced in f2003, but google it, or look in the manual... It is not a place holder, it returns the unit number, rather than command the unit number. You could open a NEWUNIT, but one would have to CLOSE and existing unit. Basically Just change all "1" to "21" and all "2" to "22". I do not know what version of fortran silverfrost is, so either -Wall or -check-all, but IMPLICIT NONE should not hurt.

Answer (score 2):

The FORMAT statements in the program use Hollerith edit descriptors, which was a feature deleted from the language as of Fortran 95.  These are notoriously error prone - character string edit descriptors should be used instead.

Hollerith edit descriptors are of the form *n*Hxxx - where *n* characters following the `H` are equivalent to a character literal.  The problem with the identified statement (at least) is that the parenthesis that is meant to close the format statement is being considered part of the literal - probably because a space or similar has been deleted from the source.

```
100 FORMAT(...9H  Depth)
                123456789
```

The error messages also identify that the variable named `File1` is not suitable as a FILE= specifier in an open statement.  This is because there is no variable declaration for `File1`, so it is assumed to be of type REAL.  There is a declaration for a variable `FiIe1`.  `IMPLICIT NONE` helps find these sorts of spelling mistakes, but the code has clearly been written using implicit typing.

These sorts of errors suggest that the source has come from optical character recognition or similar.  If so, you will need to be very mindful of OCR errors elsewhere in the source.

Comment: I took this from an old thesis from 2001, I used some OCR but I still went through it line by line. I've tried making some changes but I'm still getting problems with the spacing in FORMAT function. Is there any way to simply the FORMAT function to make it work?

Comment: The F66/FIV FORMAT(... 9H depth) would become in later Fortran FORMAT(...'DEPTH'). Or one could do... WRITE(*,123) 'Depth' and then a format line of  '123 FORMAT(A).